# VRP Stops attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4, spatial-join

I m using ArcGis 10.4.1 and Network Analyst extension. When i load locations in order to be used as Stops i lose information. ie in the following image is shown the attribute table of the location to be used
[image: Locations attribute table]

When i open Stops attribute table the following information is presented without any field from locations attribute table

[image: Stops attribute table]

How can i get the information of my locations?